# Setting authentication true with Spring Security + Spring Session

Tags: java, session, spring-security, authentication, spring-session

I have a Spring Security + Spring Session + Spring Boot project and a Controller with a custom login POST method. I have my own means to verify the credentials of the customer. Once the verification is successful, what's the best practice to access the session and set the identification to true?

I've tried this with no results:

```
    @PostMapping("/login")
    public ResponseEntity loginSubmit(@RequestBody LoginForm form) {
        Errors errors = authenticationService.validateLoginForm(form);
        if (!errors.hasErrors()) {
            CustomerDTO result = authenticationService.findCustomerByEmailAndPassword(form);
            boolean success = (result != null && result.getId() != null);
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().setAuthenticated(success);
            return new ResponseEntity(result, HttpStatus.OK);
        } else {
            return new ResponseEntity(errors.getAllErrors(), HttpStatus.OK);
        }
    }
```

How should I be doing this instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of writing your own endpoint I would suggest to integrate in Spring Security framework by implementing your own org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider

Or simply do this

```
public void login(HttpServletRequest req, String user, String pass) { 
    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authReqz = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, pass);
    Authentication auth = authManager.authenticate(authReq);

    SecurityContext sc = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
    sc.setAuthentication(auth);
    HttpSession session = req.getSession(true);
    session.setAttribute(SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT_KEY, sc);
}
```

Detailed explanation can be found [here](https://www.baeldung.com/manually-set-user-authentication-spring-security)